# Load Images and play Videos online using linux terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-12.10

I am using ubuntu 12.10 and I am browsing website using w3m module. But this module cannot shows images and play videos. Is there any way to load images and play videos in linux terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out "graphical windowing system"
and "remote desktop software" in case you are on a headless server.

Conceptually:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System

Or simply for practical purposes:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing
or
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TigerVNC

Or see more options:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software

Comment: I just want to test in my own computer.

Comment: If you already have graphic environment - 
you can run w3m-img 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2bMUtCOGko
or simply Firefox
https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/

Answer (score 0):

If you use "XTerm" the comes pre-installed on your Ubuntu system; you will be able to see images through the terminal.